# How do I profile outgoing http requests in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

What's the easiest way to make an outgoing http request in node.js while tracking time it takes to: lookup DNS, connect to server, time to first byte, time to completion, etc. ?

I've tried the `request` and `needle` modules, but they don't seem to have this functionality. Should I hack together my own solution using plain `http` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `request` actually supports an option to measure the timings by adding the `time` option:

```
request = require 'request'

opts =
    url: 'http://localhost/redirect.php'
    time: true

request opts, (e, r, body) ->
    console.log r.timingPhases
```

prints

```
{ wait: 4.005603000000008,
  dns: 0.5604900000000157,
  tcp: 0.2195809999999483,
  firstByte: 1.0195130000000177,
  download: 0.7950860000000262,
  total: 6.600273000000016 }
```

Answer (score 3):

[`request`](https://npmjs.com/package/request) wraps the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html) module so you can use the [`'socket'`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_socket) event emitted by the request object to listen for [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options) events.

Based on your question you can listen for the`'lookup'`, `'connect'`, `'data'` and `'close'` events on the Socket and use [`console.time()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_time_label) and [`console.timeEnd()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_timeend_label) to keep track of the time taken for the operation.

```
// You can use request from npm
const request = require('request')

// Or the native http/https module
// const {request} = require('https')

// Store the http.ClientRequest object returned
const req = request('https://www.google.com')

// Listen for the 'socket' event and then attach listeners to the socket
req.on('socket', socket => {
  console.time('dnsInfo')

  socket.once('lookup', (err, address, family, host) => {
    console.timeEnd('dnsInfo')
    console.log(address, family, host)
  })

  socket.once('connect', () => {
    console.time('requestTime')
    console.time('initialData')
    console.log('Connected to server')
  })

  socket.once('data', chunk => console.timeEnd('initialData'))
  socket.once('close', () => console.timeEnd('requestTime'))
})

req.end()
```